Startup notifications do not appear (Ubuntu 24.04.1)
Although I changed GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT at /etc/default/grub, (see below), my Ubuntu system does not show the startup notifications (Ubuntu 18 did show).
What should I do?
Excerpt of /etc/default/grub:
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

And:
$ uname -a
Linux 6.8.0-45-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 30 12:02:04 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS   Release:   24.04 Codename: noble

Indeed, the initial OS that receives control when booting is an Ubuntu 18 installation on an nvme; but this is an excerpt from its /etc/default/grub:
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

No "splash"; it's supposed to show the startup messages.
On system startup, it shows a selection menu list of possible systems: Ubuntu 18, Microsoft Windows 10, and Ubuntu 24.
If I select the Ubuntu 18, then when booting, it does show the startup messages.
In order to run the Ubuntu 24 system, I have to select it at the initial grub menu.
It seems that the decision to show startup messages "gets lost" when control is transferred to the Ubuntu 24 system.
Is there a way to find and control it?

You show an edit to a file; which only takes effect after a grub update; so did you kick off such an update??  and was it done in the OS that controls grub  (if the OS the change was made does not control the grub that is used on a multiboot system, the effect will be moot; as you need to make the change on the controlling OS grub)

@guiverc thank you for pointing this. Please see the extension of the initial post, that I have added. Where is the controlling statement hiding?

to see messages (not splash screen) during boot process you have to change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to "nosplash text" not an empty string.
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash text"

and after that:
sudo update-grub


@Kazemi: I tried this - it didn't help. I have Ubuntu 18 on an nvme SSD, and Windows and Ubuntu 24 on HDD partitions. I changed GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to: "nosplash text" in /etc/default/grub in both Ubuntu partitions - it's not working on the Ubuntu 24. (Grub on the Ubuntu 18 is managing the initial startup, then shows the  startup selection menu).
